# MySQL nested SELECT query with endless childs

Tags: mysql, sql, database, parent, parent-child

**My database structure**

I start with my database.

**Pages table**

```
id    content
-------------
2     My content
4     Another content
7     Example content
8     Test content
11    Some content
```

**Parents table**

```
id    page_id    parent_id
--------------------------
1     2          0
2     4          2
3     7          2
4     8          7
5     11         8
```

`parents_table.page_id` is connected to `pages_table.id`.

**Question**

- Can I with SQL get page_id 11 and climb all the parents of that id
  until I get to parent_id 0?
- The total number of parents are unknown.

**Maybe a virtual table?**

This is what I can think of, a virtual table. Just an idea, might not be the right approach.

```
id    parent_id_1    parent_id_2    parent_id_3    parent_id_4    parent_id_5
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
11    8              7              4              2              0
```

Comment: How about some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

There is no smart and elegant way to this with MySql
In Oracle you have connect by which does this work [Connect by](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It might not be [elegant](http://www.sqlsummit.com/AdjacencyList.htm), but there is a smart way to solve the problem without using 'connect by' - the [Adjacency List Model](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a stored procedure?

```
create table hier
(id int, page_id int, parent_id int);
insert into hier values
(1    , 2,          0),
(2   ,  4 ,         2),
(3  ,   7  ,        2),
(4 ,    8   ,       7),
(5,     11   ,      8);


drop procedure if exists getHier;
delimiter $$
create procedure getHier(start int)
begin

select @parent_id:=parent_id from hier where page_id = start;

drop table if exists result;
create temporary table result
(id int primary key auto_increment,
page_id int);

insert into result (page_id) values (@parent_id);

while @parent_id != 0 DO 
insert into result (page_id)
select @parent_id:=parent_id from hier where page_id = @parent_id;

end while;

select page_id from result order by id;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Then do

```
call getHier(11)
```

Result:

```
page_id
8
7
2
0
```

BTW, your desired output is wrong ;)